# Personalize Mobile Connect SMS Not Working in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I am  trying to Personalize SMS which is used in Journeybuilder.
I am not receiving the SMS.

When i use `"SUBSCRIBERKEY",@Subscriberkey` in `lookuporderrows()` I am able to receive SMS but not with Personalization.

When i use `"SUBSCRIBERKEY",@idSubscribe`r in `lookuporderrows()` i am not receiving the SMS.

Below is my code

```
%%[ 

SET @idSubscriber = MOBILE_NUMBER 
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SMS_Journey_2_interest", 1, "MeetingDate Asc", "SubscriberKey",@idSubscriber) 
SET @RowCount = RowCount(@rows) 

IF (Rowcount(@rows) > 0) THEN 
    VAR @ILRow, @name, @meetingtype 
    SET @ILRow = row(@rows,1) 
    SET @meetingDate = field(@ILRow,"MeetingDate")
ENDIF 

]%%

%%[ if @meetingdate > Now() then ]%%

    Hi %%=Field(@ILRow,"FirstName")=%%, we want to remind you about the upcoming meeting 
    that you have with us next %%=Format(@meetingdate,"MM/dd/yyyy")=%% at 
    %%=Field(@ILRow,"MeetingPlaceAddress")=%% starting at %%=Field(@ILRow,"TimeFrom")=%%. 
    If you can't make it please send us a What's up at:

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Same code is working in Email, but not in SMS.

Comment: Try using `_subscriberkey` (The personalization string)

Comment: Your email send DE probably has the `SubscriberKey` column while your mobile DE one doesnt

Comment: @Data_Kid can you please specify specifically? i am not getting you here.

Comment: @Data_Kid i have tried with ` SET @idSubscriber = _MobileNumber ` but its not working!!
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, its working  for me. when you are doing lookup use DE filed which is Mobilenumber field.

```
%%[ 

SET @idSubscriber = MOBILE_NUMBER 
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SMS_Journey_2_interest", 1, "MeetingDate Asc", "MobilePhone",@idSubscriber) 
SET @RowCount = RowCount(@rows) 

IF (Rowcount(@rows) > 0) THEN 
    VAR @ILRow, @name, @meetingtype 
    SET @ILRow = row(@rows,1) 
    SET @meetingDate = field(@ILRow,"MeetingDate")
ENDIF 

]%%

%%[ if @meetingdate > Now() then ]%%

    Hi %%=Field(@ILRow,"FirstName")=%%, we want to remind you about the upcoming 
    info meeting that you have with us next %%=Format(@meetingdate,"MM/dd/yyyy")=%% 
    at %%=Field(@ILRow,"MeetingPlaceAddress")=%% starting at %%=Field(@ILRow,"TimeFrom")=%%.
    If you can't make it please send us a What's up at:

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to do this via regular SMS send in MobileConnect?

Because as far as I know we are not able to look up other attributes tables for MobileConnect SMS personalization.

You can only use attributes that are available on MobileConnect Demographics table and not from anywhere else.

Comment: i have updated my code, i tried with mobile connect but no success.